# High latency when using DolphinDB subscription to Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, dolphindb

I wrote the following code to subscribe to Kafka:

```
subscribeTable(tableName="tab_share17", actionName="device", handler=power14, msgAsTable=true, batchSize=1, throttle=10)
```

It takes quite a long time for the system to read the data. What can be done to reduce the latency?

Answer (score 0):

Setting batchSize=1 means only one data record is processed each time. So I'd suggest setting batchSize=1000 to process more data one time.
Note that when throttle=10, if less than 1000 data records arrive in 10s, the handler will be triggered to process the incoming messages.